# Android AlertDialog Not Showing Any Content

Tags: java, android

I'm learning Android and I'm using Google documentation to follow some examples and learn the basis. I was following this guide: ["Android Dialogs"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) and using the same code they show but I cannot manage my app to show de AlertDialog properly. When I tap the button, the screen slightly darkens but any type of dialog appears.

I've created a specific class for the dialog with this code:

```
public class NuevaAveriaDialogo extends DialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Mensaje")
            .setPositiveButton("Guardar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it

    return builder.create();
   }
}
```

And this is the code in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DialogFragment dialogoNuevaAveria;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialogoNuevaAveria = new DialogFragment();
            dialogoNuevaAveria.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"averia");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating the Parent `DialogFragment` class instead of your custom class `NuevaAveriaDialogo`.

Change `dialogoNuevaAveria = new DialogFragment();`

to `dialogoNuevaAveria = new NuevaAveriaDialogo();`

So your fab listener will be

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dialogoNuevaAveria = new NuevaAveriaDialogo();
        dialogoNuevaAveria.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"averia");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity, create a new instance of  **NuevaAveriaDialogo** instead of **DialogFragment**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialogoNuevaAveria = new NuevaAveriaDialogo();
            dialogoNuevaAveria.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"averia");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are just using the standard `DialogFragment` which returns a simple `Dialog` in the `onCreateDialog` method.

To use your `NuevaAveriaDialogo`  use:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NuevaAveriaDialogo dialogoNuevaAveria;

    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 
    //....

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialogoNuevaAveria = new NuevaAveriaDialogo();
            dialogoNuevaAveria.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"averia");
        }
    });
}
```